# Formula for derivative of the inverse function

Tags: derivatives

How to deduce formula for $\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)$ knowing that $\sinh(x)=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$, $\sinh'(x)=\cosh x$ and $(f^{-1}(x))'=\dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ ?

Comment: Did you even try anything? All you need is given, so if you had just plugged in everything in that last formula you would have obtained the result yourself.

Comment: I do not understand your indignation. I've tried, but I couldn't. I've explained in my comment under the answer which fragment I don't understand..

Comment: If Alex had answered simply $\mathrm{arcsinh}'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$, would it have helped you? You want others to explain what they did, so the least we can ask is you to do the same.

Comment: Ok, in future I will think twice before I ask, but nobody yelled at me because of my questions before, so I didn't realise that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Letting $f(x)=\sinh(x)$ we have $f'(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}=\cosh(x)$ thus $$(f^{-1}(x))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}=\frac{1}{\cosh(\mathrm{arcsinh}(x))}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$

It is worth noting that the formula $(f^{-1}(x))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ comes from the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), as $$1=\frac{d}{dx} x=\frac{d}{dx}f(f^{-1}(x))=f'(f^{-1}(x))(f^{-1}(x))'$$ so rearranging gives the desired result.

Comment: I don't understand this:
$\frac{1}{\cosh(\mathrm{arcsinh}(x))}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$
Where it came from?

Comment: @xan: It comes from $\cosh^2 w-\sinh^2 w=1$, which can be verified directly from the definition of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$.

Comment: now I understand everything, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

To find $$y=\operatorname{arcsinh} x = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
put $t= e^x$, which leads to an easy equation.